# Light switch controlling bedroom ceiling fan also flickering adjacent room

Tags: electrical, bathroom, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have not seen this question asked. Just bought a House built in 90s, suddenly noticed that when i flick a bedroom fan off, the adjacent room bathroom light/fan flickers as if it were controlled by this switch? It only shuts off briefly and comes back on. What could be the culprit? Is this something serious? Old light switches need replaced, they are original. Thanks. If photos needed please let me know?

Comment: Is the light that flickers an LED bulb?

Comment: Type of light bulb/s?  LEDs do tend to have more flickering problems with minor voltage/power changes(turning a switch on/off).  90s almost new for switches/receptacles, but it would not be too much to check the tightness of the connections.

Comment: One of the lights is LED one is not, aren’t they best way to go?

Comment: LEDs are the best for saving/using the least amount of electricity.  They also use electronics inside of them, that are sometimes not the best at evening out electric changes.  It tends to make it harder to determine if it is the LED or a problem with the wires.

Comment: Try a different LED lamp. Some are more prone to flicker than others.